# c# get html tag inside content and next element with regex

Tags: c#, regex

This is my html:

```
    <div class="_50f3">
Followed by 
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/zurabj/followers">
        7,583 people
    </a>
    </div>

<div class="_50f3">
Friends
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/zurabj/followers">
200 people
</a>
</div>
```

As you can see there are two divs with the same classname. What i want to achive is to get followers count(7583 people). I know this would be easy with htmlagilitypack, but in this case i can't use it and need to solve the problem with regex, but  can't figure out how.

And problem also is that, i don't know ordering, sometimes friends count is inside the first and sometimes in the second div.

Answer (score 3):

Okey i solve the problem

```
string html = fb.GetHtml("https://www.facebook.com/zurabj?fref=ts");
                string pattern = "<div class=\"_50f3\".*?>(.*?)<\\/div>";
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, pattern);
                foreach (Match m in matches)
                {
                    if (m.ToString().Contains("Followed by"))
                    {

                        Match count = Regex.Match(m.ToString(), "<a .*?>(.*?)<\\/a>");
                        string counterString = count.Groups[1].ToString();
                    }
```

Comment: Why not inserting "Followed by" inside of the first pattern, so you won't need to check with Contains.